# Spring boot - How to avoid using new in Spring boot class annotated as component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        listOfProviders.add(racfAuthenticationProvider);
        listOfProviders.add(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
        return new CustomProviderManager(listOfProviders); // <- have a look here
    }
}
```

***CustomProviderManager*** declaration:

```
@Component
public class CustomProviderManager extends ProviderManager {

private AuthenticationEventPublisher eventPublisher = new NullEventPublisher();
private AuthenticationManager parent;
private boolean eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = true;

public CustomProviderManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
    super(providers);
}
```

As can be seen from the code snippet above:

`return new CustomProviderManager(listOfProviders);`

Produces the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customProviderManager' defined in file [/opt/hsd/tomcat-9.0.43/webapps/csesonlineapp/WEB-INF/classes/gov/nm/cses/gen/CustomProviderManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig' defined in file [/opt/hsd/tomcat-9.0.43/webapps/csesonlineapp/WEB-INF/classes/gov/nm/cses/gen/SpringSecurityConfig.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [gov.nm.cses.gen.SpringSecurityConfig] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader^M
> context: csesonlineapp^M
> delegate: false^M
> ----------> Parent Classloader:^M
> java.net.URLClassLoader@38bc8ab5

I believe this is happening due to a `new` operator instead of Autowiring when classes are annotated as Component. Please correct me if I am wrong.

***How can I avoid using new in the above case?***

Comment: Where did you initialise `listOfProviders` and also how look declarations for `racfAuthenticationProvider` & `ldapAuthenticationProvider()`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the class `CustomProviderManager` to be component - using @Component?

Just remove @Component from the class, the problem will be gone.

If you want autowire `AuthenticationManager`, just autowire in `SpringSecurityConfig` class